# How puts all array items in HAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Cant print all items in array. What I doing wrong ?

```
=@questionn.each do |item|
=item.to_s
```

Error is: unterminated string meets end of file, syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Answer (score 3):

haml is based on 2 space indentations.  All you have to do to fix your code is indent the next line by 2 spaces. You may also want to use `-` instead of `=` for the first line so it doesn't output the returned value of `#each`

```
- @questionn.each do |item|
  = item.to_s
```